# Как сменить положение стандартных кнопок управления картой?

Tags: android, google-maps

Нужно выставить внизу над кнопками зума кнопку текущее положение с привязкой к первым чтоб при разных разрешениях отступ не менялся. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое можно делать двумя способами:

1. Аццкие хаки по нахождения кнопок в контейнере карты и задавания им нужного местоположения. Вот пример для кнопки компаса:

```
/**
 * hack for moving compas
 */
public static void moveCompas(final View mapView) {
    try {
        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton").getParent();
        parent.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Resources r = mapView.getResources();
                    //convert our dp margin into pixels
                    int marginPixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, r.getDisplayMetrics());
                    //increase top as we have search
                    int marginPixelsTop = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20 + 64, r.getDisplayMetrics());
                    // Get the map compass view
                    View mapCompass = parent.getChildAt(4);

                    // create layoutParams, giving it our wanted width and height(important, by default the width is "match parent")
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mapCompass.getHeight(), mapCompass.getHeight());
                    // position on top right
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);
                    //give compass margin
                    rlp.setMargins(marginPixels, marginPixelsTop, marginPixels, marginPixels);
                    mapCompass.setLayoutParams(rlp);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.ex(TAG, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

Остальные кнопки надо делать аналогично и иметь в виду что при обновлении SDK карт всё это может поменяться и придётся заново писать эти хаки

2. Заменить кнопки собственной реализацией. Т.е. беряёте и помещаете свои кнопки поверх карты и реализовываете нужный функционал.

---

SDK карт не предоставляет нужного вам функционала и без множества боли вам вашу задачу не решить

Comment: Спасибо! Буду юзать кастомные вью